# use regex to pull one or 2 words

Tags: regex

Input:

```
"2012 Dodge Challenger SRT8, Supercharged, Amber White $40,000"
"2013 Audi s7, Prestige Package, Grey $79,000"
"2014 Porsche 911, Black $113,000"
"2015 Range Rover Sport, Navy Blue $84,000"
```

Expected Output:

```
Amber White
Grey
Black
Navy Blue
```

I would like to scrape this info using a regex and outwit hub.
I have successfully scraped most of it using mark (`,`) before and after in outwit, but where I am having trouble is some listings have a 2 word color and some have one. "`Amber White, Grey, Black Mist...`".
Also I can't use the mark before or after because these words are inside of the unique phrases.
Can anyone help me with how to extract the color info, accurately with regex.

Comment: So it always `Year, MAKE MODEL, TYPE, COLOR PRICE`?

Comment: yes for the most part

Comment: ok that worked like a charm. But maybe this doesnt work for other listings like say electronics. I have to pull color data like this from multiple different listings (similar in format though) and some don't list the price. Thought the solution would be universal. That's my mistake for not mentioning that.

Comment: no that doesn't work either. TERRIBLE, lol finally got the regex I need and cant even use it with outwit hub. I'll do some Googling to see what could possibly be the problem.

Comment: Well, make sure you upvote or accept (click the faded arrow) next to the answers that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
(?<=,\s)(\w+|\w+\s+\w+)(?=\s+(?:\$|\d|Size))
```

Test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/tG2nX8/6)

NOTE: This assumes that the price **ALWAYS** has a dollar sign before it and that the color is **ALWAYS** directly before the price

### Test:

```
"2012 Dodge Challenger SRT8, Supercharged, Amber White $40,000"   
"2013 Audi s7, Prestige Package, Grey $79,000"   
"2014 Porsche 911, Black $113,000" 
"2015 Range Rover Sport, Navy Blue $84,000"
"Amazon Fire Phone, Black 32GB (AT&T)" 
"LG G3, Fire Red 16GB (Tmobile)
Diesel Jeans, Safado Straight, Midnight Black Size 36/34
```

### Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [43-54] `Amber White`
MATCH 2
1.  [98-102]    `Grey`
MATCH 3
1.  [132-137]   `Black`
MATCH 4
1.  [174-183]   `Navy Blue`
MATCH 5
1.  [213-218]   `Black`
MATCH 6
1.  [241-249]   `Fire Red`
MATCH 7
1.  [296-310]   `Midnight Black`
```

### Breakdown of the Regex:

`(?<=,\s)`:Assert that there is a `,<space>` before the COLOR
`(\w+|\w+\s+\w+)`:Find and capture the letters which make up COLOR
`(?=\s+(?:\$|\d|Size))`:Assert that there is a  followed by a `$` OR a digit OR the string `Size` to the right of the COLOR

Comment: hey thx for the suggestion. It did pull the colors into a column but it also pulled all the pricing and other info as well (into the same column).

Comment: You should be able to reference the match within the parens with a `\1` or something. What language are you using?

Comment: hey I tried your suggestion out and it does grab the color but also grabs info afterwards like "32GB"(i had to remove the $) in the phone listings and the pricing in the car listings. If possible could it be very specific to the colors. Is that even possible?

Comment: Are you sure? It returns the color correctly for the cars and phone. But not "Diesel Jeans, Safado Straight, Midnight Black Size 36/34". Please post a wide variety of the product in your original question so we can test on it

Comment: That regex snippet you created works perfectly!!! I've tried in the regex tester on multiple different scenarios and it always grabbed just color info just like I need! Thx a bunch! Any idea why outwit hub doesn't recognize it?

Comment: You might need to put slashes (`/`) around the regex?

Comment: As in  `/(?<=,\s)(\w+|\w+\s+\w+)(?=\s+(?:\$|\d|Size))/`
Or maybe look at this [link](http://onlinejournalismblog.com/2012/11/07/scraping-using-regular-expressions-in-outwit-hub-part-2-special-characters-negative-matches-and-more/) for more ideas

Comment: ho do I like the answer that helped me? im new here

Comment: To the left of an answer there's a number with up arrow and a down arrow. And then under that is a faded grey check mark. Click the up arrow for a post that helped you and the check mark for the best one.

Comment: Ok I "checked" this answer but I need 15 reputations to use the up arrows.

Answer (score 1):

here you go, here is an elegent solution using positive look behind and a positive look ahead

**Regex**

```
(?<=,\s)([\w\s]+)(?=\s\$)
```

**Test String**

```
"2012 Dodge Challenger SRT8, Supercharged, Amber White $40,000"
"2013 Audi s7, Prestige Package, Grey $79,000"
"2014 Porsche 911, Black $113,000"
"2015 Range Rover Sport, Navy Blue $84,000"
```

**Result**

MATCH 1

1. [43-54] `Amber White`

MATCH 2

1. [97-101]    `Grey`

MATCH 3

1. [130-135]   `Black`

MATCH 4

1. [171-180]   `Navy Blue`

try at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/cM3mA3/1)

Comment: ok that worked like a charm. But maybe this doesnt work for other listings like say electronics. I have to pull color data like this from multiple different listings (similar in format though) and some don't list the price. Thought the solution would be universal. That's my mistake for not mentioning that."Amazon Fire Phone, Black 32GB (AT&T)" "LG G3, Fire Red 16GB (Tmobile)" is there a happy medium that will make that above regex snippet work with similair formatted listings. Like the phone listings as well as the car listings? thx again

Comment: you may perhaps list down the possible scenarios, may I try to get a common regex for all.

Comment: possible scenario's-----"2013 Audi s7, Prestige Package, Grey $79,000" "LG G3, Fire Red 16GB (Tmobile)" "Diesel Jeans, Safado Straight, Midnight Black Size 36/34"